# Term of Art Designation for a Tightrope Walker's Balancing Pole

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, translation

One hot and humid summer day--7 August 1974, to be precise--my father, in a tone of unusual excitation, bellowed for me to join him in our living room where he directed my attention to the television set. On screen, a live video-feed showed a man dressed in black who appeared to be floating on thin air between two skyscrapers, an occurrence I had previously understood to be impossible. Soon it became clear that the young man wasn’t actually floating on thin air, he was standing on thin wire (hey, I’m somewhat credulous!).

That young man was the practitioner of tightrope walking or *funambulism*, which is the art of walking along a thin wire or rope. It has a long tradition in various countries and is commonly associated with the circus.

[image]

As can be seen in the photograph taken that same summer afternoon, the wire walker, a young Frenchman named Philippe Petit, is holding a flexible pole of fifteen or twenty feet length. A little research revealed that tightrope walkers often use these poles to maintain what is a rather precarious balance. The apparatus distributes mass away from the walker’s pivot point, increasing the moment of inertia and reducing angular acceleration because a greater force is required to rotate the performer over the wire. The result is less tipping. In addition the wire walker can correct sway by rotating the pole, which creates a compensating torque on the body.

Though tightrope walking can claim an enduring and international pedigree, and the balancing pole plays an important part in the success and safety of the tightrope walker's practice, I have been unable to discover a name for the apparatus other than the disappointingly generic and pedestrian, *balancing pole*.

Does the device have a *term of art* designation?

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything other than _balancing pole_, either. Do you think they really need fancy jargon for it?

Comment: ***Balancing pole*** is the more common definition. Balance pole or bar are also used. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=balancing+pole%2Cbalancing+bar%2Cbalance+pole%2C+balance+bar+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbalancing%20pole%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbalancing%20bar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbalance%20pole%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbalance%20bar%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Not an answer to you question, but there is a documentary called "Man on Wire" about Philippe and this stunt.  It's available on Netflix streaming.

Comment: @Barmar, I don't know whether a fancy name is needed or not. But I would imagine that, in a tradition as enduring, widespread and specialized as tightrope walking, such a term of art would have developed in one or more languages. If so, I'd be interested in knowing those terms and their English translations.

Comment: It seems to me that they have a term of art for the wire itself (_slackline_), but nothing other than balancing pole for the pole.

Comment: @James, indeed, I'm a great fan of Mr. Petit and own a copy of the documentary - which is excellent, BTW. Additionally, a new feature film by Robert Zemeckis  starring Joseph Gordon-Levit, is scheduled for release this fall. And I can't wait. :-)

Comment: The rope-dancing is performed by a woman *holding a balancing pole*; and on the same rope a man, probably "clown to the rope," is represented hanging by one leg with his head downwards. (1801) https://books.google.it/books?id=eJwSAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA172&dq=%22balancing+pole%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAmoVChMIl4iHjLGBxwIVw1sUCh3dVwMW#v=onepage&q=%22balancing%20pole%22&f=false

Comment: @Josh61, thanks 61, as I was relating to Barmar, I find it hard to imagine that such a specialized tool, among such an insular and international group wouldn't have, over the centuries, developed a specialized *in-word* for the object in question. You must be in France, eh?

Comment: I have just finished watching *Man on Wire* :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou, hey there! So, what did you think, right thumb up, or left thumb down?

Comment: I've written an email, I am a fan. A question dated 2008 from metafilter asks [Name that 10-foot pole!](http://ask.metafilter.com/83448/Name-that-10foot-pole). Balance pole seems to be the only answer. However, the  **Oribat** is a person who dances on the rope; the **Neurobat** is a high wire artist; and the **Schoenobat** flies down the rope: http://www.blondinmemorialtrust.com/funambulus

Comment: In Italian it has two names, the oldest derived from Fr *balancier*, is **bilanciere**,  the second is [**asta  d’equilibrio**](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_sinonimi_contrari/B/bilanciere.shtml) (equilibrium pole). I believe *statera* is  "scales" or/and [*steelyard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steelyard_balance).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting links @Mari-Lou, glad you're a fan. [Philippe Petit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Petit)’s unauthorized feat (which he referred to as "*le coup*") took place 1,350-feet (400-*metres*) above the ground. Petit rigged a 450-pound (200-*kilogram*) cable, and used a custom-made 26-foot (8-*metre*) long, 55-pound (25-*kilogram*) balancing pole. Won't you post, dear?

Comment: I checked out those links @Mari-Lou, that's great stuff. Really appreciate it, been on my mind for some time now.

Answer (score 2):

The Latin for it is **statera** which also means a 'weighing balance.' I don't know if the balance pole meaning is classical or medieval.

If anyone can reproduce the OED entry they should find something under **static** and **stater.**

I think it is a **"static pole."**  But that is probably not current among funambulists. This illustration for the beginning of LIBRA is an elaborate pun on **statera** from a twelfth Century Calendar.

This picture is from  Lansdowne MS 383 **BRITISH LIBRARY**
The shaftesbury psalter created for the queen. 12th century
The Benedictine nunnery of St. Edward, Shaftesbury, Dorset:

[image: pun on statera]

Comment: Excellent, Hugh! Thank you very much, I lack the wherewithal to access the OED, too - but I knew it would lead to something, +!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the most likely term is 'pole'.

"Hand me my pole".

"Where did I leave my pole?"

There is no other kind of pole used in wire-walking so I imagine the word 'balancing' would be superfluous.

Comment: Yeah, I get it already chasly. It's just his *shtick*. ;-)